# Why Are Deleted Posts Showing Up in Paginated Posts in Jekyll Blog?

Tags: pagination, jekyll, blogs, posts

I have a Jekyll blog. I deleted many of the blog posts because they were very old. However, they are still showing up in my categories (paginator.posts). Here's the code:

```
      <div class="post-list">

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <article class="clearfix post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">
          <h2 class="h2">{{ post.title | remove: "| SiteName" }}</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="meta">
              {% assign d = post.date | date: "%-d"  %}
              {{ post.date | date: "%B" }} 
              {{ d }}, 
              {{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}
              {% if site.data.authors[post.author.login] %}
                {% assign author = site.data.authors[post.author.login] %}
                  by <a href="{{ author.link }}" title="Posts by {{ author.name }}" rel="author">{{ author.name }}</a><br>
              {% endif %}
          </p>
          <p>
            {% if post.meta.thumbnail_asset and post.meta.thumbnail_alt %}
              <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.meta.thumbnail_alt }}">
                {% asset '{{ post.meta.thumbnail_asset }}' alt='{{ post.meta.thumbnail_alt }}' class="wp-blog-thumbnail img-lt" %}
              </a>
            {% elsif post.meta.thumbnail_asset %}
              <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">
                {% asset '{{ post.meta.thumbnail_asset }}' alt='{{ post.title | strip_html | truncatewords: 5 }}' class="wp-blog-thumbnail img-lt" %}
              </a>
            {% elsif post.meta.thumbnail_url and post.meta.thumbnail_alt %}
              <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.meta.thumbnail_alt }}">
                <img src="{{ post.meta.thumbnail_url }}" class="wp-blog-thumbnail img-lt" alt="{{ post.meta.thumbnail_alt }}">
              </a>
            {% elsif post.meta.thumbnail_url %}
              <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">
                <img src="{{ post.meta.thumbnail_url }}" class="wp-blog-thumbnail img-lt" alt="{{ post.title | strip_html | truncatewords: 5 }}">
              </a>
          {% endif %}
          {% if post.description %}
              {{ post.description }}..
            {{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 55 }}
          {% endif %}<a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">Read More &raquo;</a>
          </p>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
</div> <!-- end post-list -->
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how you deleted you posts, but the docs state: "Pagination pages through every post in the posts variable unless a post has hidden: true in its front matter."

Comment: I saw that but I already deleted the posts and now they are not in my repository. On the category and author pages the thumbnail and description show up but when you click to go to the article there is a 404. Not sure where it's getting the information.

Comment: Share more code please

Comment: Have you tried running `jekyll clean` before restarting the server?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this? I am having the same problem. Jekyll clean did not work.

Comment: This is an old question without a real answer. Consider posting a new question sharing your specific details.